# How to view data in struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to view data  from databases from jsp so now I come up with idea by  without any scriplet or Java code in jsp .I have learned a modeldriven and some interceptors to use in struts.xml  but I don't know how to implement it ?so could some one guide and help to go further am new to strut2 world

**Beantest:**

```
public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBook()
    {
        return Book;
    }

    public void setBook(String book)
    {
        Book = book;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return Author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author)
    {
        Author = author;
    }

    public String getAvailbleqty()
    {
        return Availbleqty;
    }

    public void setAvailbleqty(String availbleqty)
    {
        Availbleqty = availbleqty;
    }

    public String getCategory()
    {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category)
    {
        Category = category;
    }
```

**DataAction.java:**

```
public List<Beantest> viewbook()
{

    List<Beantest> al=new ArrayList<Beantest>();
    Beantest bt = new Beantest();
    try
    {
        String sql = "select * from Bookavaible";
        Statement stmt;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            bt.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            bt.setBook(rs.getString("Book"));
            bt.setAuthor(rs.getString("Author"));
            bt.setAvailbleqty(rs.getString("Availbleqty"));
            bt.setCategory(rs.getString("Category"));
            al.add(bt);
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return al;

}
```

**Actiontest.java**

```
 public class ActionTest {
    Beantest bt;

    private List<Beantest> beans;

    public String viewbookaction()
    {
        DataAction da = new DataAction();
        beans = da.viewbook();
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Beantest> getBeans()
    {
        return beans;
    }
```

**Bookview.jsp:**

```
<s:action name="VBA">
        <td>id:</td>

        <td>Book:</td>

        <td>Author:</td>

        <td>Availbleqty:</td>

        <td>Category:</td>

</s:action>
```

**web.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>BookView.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

**strut2.xml**

```
<package name="a" namespace="/">
    <action name="VBA" class="Action.ActionTest" method="viewbookaction">
        <result name="success">/BookView.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: you can use struts2 tags to display data (eg property tag ) by binding data from action

Comment: thank for u reply if u have time kindly provide solution

Comment: Please look at essentially any S2 tutorial. Also, do you really need to use the `<s:action>` tag here? I don't see why.

Comment: k fine i am learning only but i dono how to pass value from xml to jsp without using javacode

Comment: Exact solution refer http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-html-form-data-to-struts2-action-by-model-driven-method/

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `s:action` tag in JSP, until you know how and why to do that. To display values in JSP you are not needed it at all. You should use struts tags to access action bean properties. For example you can print values to the JSP out using `s:property` tag. For example

```
<s:iterator value="beans">    
    id: <s:property value="id"/><br>    
    Book: <s:property value="book"/><br>    
    Author: <s:property value="author"/><br>
    Availbleqty: <s:property value="availbleqty"/><br>    
    Category: <s:property value="category"/><br>    
<s:/iterator>
```

The `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated and you should replace it with `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`. See [`web.xml`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html) docs. Also see this answer for
[Need suggestions regarding project implementation in Struts and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17898392/573032).

Comment: fine sir i will follow but it can't show a single value in jsp page?? i dont now why??

Comment: The value in JSP will be available after you call an action and return result with this JSP.

Comment: ya sir i called a Action with method name method="viewbookaction" and result page is "Bookview jsp"

Comment: What is the size of list returned by `viewbook()` method? And remove `ModelDriven` from your action class, because I don't see it in the question.

Comment: while i am printing list it return value  like "list[Beanclass.Beantest@1e87539]"

Comment: `list`? it should be `beans`.

Comment: bt.setId(rs.getString("id"));
    bt.setBook(rs.getString("Book"));
    bt.setAuthor(rs.getString("Author"));
    bt.setAvailbleqty(rs.getString("Availbleqty"));
    bt.setCategory(rs.getString("Category"));
    al.add(bt);
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
    {
     System.out.println("list"+al);
    }

Comment: this how i printed a list

Comment: And what is the `al.size()`? Also did you read my previous comments?

Answer (score 1):

Change your web.xml and stuts.xml as below.

Struts.xml

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="a" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="" class="Action.ActionTest" method="viewbookaction">
        <result name="success">/BookView.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

That's all. Simply run.

Comment: thanks for u r effort it not showing a Result i will check my side and  will Update here??